# Parsing a JSON string

Tags: json, parsing

```
{
    "jsonStringData": " ["Coil",{"CHARGE_ID":"T862270","PROD_ID":"S878412","COMBINE_SPLIT_IND":"S",
    "WEIGHT":"234244","FEET":"3535","ORDER_NUMBER":"LI91004","OIL_DRY_IND":"D",
    "NEXT_FACILITY":"WHSE",      "DEFECT_CODE":"","TEST_CUT_IND":"","NSTD_FAC_REASON_CODE":"",
    "COMMENTS":"","SCRAP_FEET":""}]"
}
```

When I parsed above JSONString using "http://jsonlint.com/", it gives me below error message. I am not sure what that error mean.

Please help me to get the right JSONString.

***Error :***

```
Parse error on line 2:
...sonStringData": " ["Coil",{"CHARGE_ID":"
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

Comment: {
    "jsonStringData": " [{"CHARGE_ID":"T862270","PROD_ID":"S878412",
 "COMBINE_SPLIT_IND":"S","WEIGHT":"353455","FEET":"3535","ORDER_NUMBER":"LI91004","OIL_DRY_IND":"D",
 "NEXT_FACILITY":"WHSE","DEFECT_CODE":"","TEST_CUT_IND":"","NSTD_FAC_REASON_CODE":"","COMMENTS":"",
    "SCRAP_FEET":""}]"
} I have deleted First JSONArray called "Coil" from JSONString, but still getting the same error message.                            Parse error on line 2:
...onStringData": " [{"CHARGE_ID":"T862270"
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote just before `Coil` ends the string which was a value. Just after this string you should have either `}` or `,` :

[image]

(from [json.org](http://json.org/))

But it looks like the error was to put a json encoded array into quotes when building the complete object.

You should probably have

```
"jsonStringData": ["C...
```

instead of

```
"jsonStringData": " ["C...
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `"` after the `:` and also the closing one at the end.

```
{
    "jsonStringData": [
        "Coil",
        {
            "CHARGE_ID": "T862270",
            "PROD_ID": "S878412",
            "COMBINE_SPLIT_IND": "S",
            "WEIGHT": "234244",
            "FEET": "3535",
            "ORDER_NUMBER": "LI91004",
            "OIL_DRY_IND": "D",
            "NEXT_FACILITY": "WHSE",
            "DEFECT_CODE": "",
            "TEST_CUT_IND": "",
            "NSTD_FAC_REASON_CODE": "",
            "COMMENTS": "",
            "SCRAP_FEET": ""
        }
    ]
}
```